# How to activate the sbt DockerPlugin in scala?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I have two scala projects, one is already defined to build its docker container through the sbt docker plugin. The other one I want to dockerify as well.

The working one has in its `build.sbt` the following lines relevant to the docker config:

```
organization := "com.namespace"
name := "dockerized-app"
version := sys.env.getOrElse("PIPELINE_VERSION", "0.1.0_local")
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
packageName in Docker := packageName.value
dockerRepository := Some("our-docker.io:5001")
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080)
```

I thought that I could copy paste the relevant lines to the new project, change the name, and make it work.

Yet when I add the line to the about to be dockerified scala project:

```
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
```

I get the error:

```
 Cannot resolve symbol DockerPlugin
```

I've looked through the prexisting projects `libraryDependencies`, yet it doesn't seem to be configured that way. In the the pre-configured project, IntellJ somehow knows the plugin, I can track that the `DockerPlugin` comes from `com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker`. This made me assume that `sbt` comes shipped with it by default.

Yet apparently I have to activate it somehow.

Digging deeper I also tried adding this to my `plugins.sbt` to no avail:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.2")
```

How to activate `DockerPlugin` using sbt in scala?

Comment: Did you check if
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.2") is in your project/plugins.sbt file?

Comment: @P3trur0 I did just that, and run `sbt update` -- yet it still seems unable to find it.

Comment: then it seems fine to me. Are u using building from intelliJ? Did you try to refresh the project itself or run the sbt from command prompt directly?

Comment: @P3trur0 You can post the addSbtPlugin line as an answer for me to upvote and accept. There was some weird resolving issue, yet after resetting the project, restarting intellij, and then adding the plugin first and then adding the changes to the build.sbt, it works as expected now. No idea what went wrong within intellij though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it working properly you need to add the following line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.2")
```

in your `project/plugins.sbt` file.

Then refresh your project and it should work.

For further information, please check the [Sbt Native Packager documentation](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).